# Create a single column based off another in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns

I cannot find any help on this what so ever.

In tableau i want to create a column that defines if something is "Valid" or "Invalid" based off another column.

For example if something is 50/50 (within a 5% range either way) i want to say "Valid" otherwise "Invalid"

At the moment i can only separate it out by 1's and 0's using numerous calculated fields...

```
CASE ATTR([EventLabel])
WHEN "Control"
THEN SUM ([Sessions])/TOTAL(SUM([Sessions]))ELSE 0 END
```

AND

```
CASE ATTR([EventLabel])
WHEN "Experiment"
THEN SUM ([Sessions])/TOTAL(SUM([Sessions]))ELSE 0 END
```

Then i create this:

```
IF [Control Sessions]>=0.47
AND [Experiment Sessions]<=0.53
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

To obtain if the attribute is valid or not....but i dont want it over 2 columns (as per the screen shot) and ideally i would like it to say "Valid" or "Invalid" in 1 column only

[image]

Is this even possible?

[Full screenshot of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uHfK.jpg)

Comment: Is your current calculation working? You can include multiple entries in a case/if statement `if  ATTR([EventLabel]) = 'Control'    THEN SUM ([Sessions])/TOTAL(SUM([Sessions])) 
elseif  
 ATTR([EventLabel]) = 'Experiment' THEN  SUM ([Sessions])/TOTAL(SUM([Sessions])) 
 else ''  end`

Comment: If @Aron s answer doesn't help, could you provide a screenshot of the whole application window? It's a lot easier to see what you are doing and how you organise your visualisation this way.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample data so that the calculations and the reason to calculate are easily understandable. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the current calculations above do work - i have separated them out rather than just making it into one statement. Thanks for the responses so far.  Can i add an AND statement within that.  ie `if ATTR([EventLabel]) = 'Control' **AND** SUM [Sessions])/TOTAL(SUM([Sessions]))=>0.47 THEN "Valid" ElseIf if ATTR([EventLabel]) = 'Experiment' **AND** SUM [Sessions])/TOTAL(SUM([Sessions]))<=0.53 THEN "Invalid"`

Comment: The idea is to take the sessions for Control and Experiment and then basically say if its close to a 50/50 split- if its within a certain threshold (ie 3%) then its Valid else its Invalid. I just want the words Invalid or Valid at the end of the row to give me a distinctive answer